# What is the time-complexity of this program (c++)

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, code-complexity

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> flatten(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const &vec)
{
    std::vector<T> flattened;
    for (auto const &v: vec) {
        flattened.insert(flattened.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
    }
    return flattened;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    };
 
    std::vector<int> flattened = flatten(vec);
    for (int &i: flattened) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Is the time complexity of the above code O(n) or O(n^2)? I know it is only a single for() loop, but will using insert() inside of a for loop will make it O(n^2)?

Comment: Ask yourself how many times your loop examines the same element. Also ask yourself _where_ the insertion takes place, and how many values must be shuffled to make room for it in that position.

Comment: Also consider the reallocations that will be potentially required when you insert values into `flattened`.

Comment: So is it O(n^2)?

Comment: Amortized time complexity of reallocation to grow a `std::vector` is constant.

Comment: the first question to answer is: What is `n` ? The code you posted has always the same input, all hardcoded values, it cannot increase, hence running the code takes a constant amount of time (modulo other factors that do not depend on the size of the input)

Comment: According to the documentation insertion has a complexity of O(n). Since you're doing it n times (where n is the size of the the vector) it has complexity O(n*n = n^2)

Comment: considering only the `flatten` function, `n` could be total number of elements, number of outer vectors, or number of inner vectors

Comment: @MarcusRost no, the documentation states it is _"Constant plus linear in the distance between pos and end of the container."_ and of course that distance in this case is zero.

Comment: @MWaleedMalik explain why you think it is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Since there is no `std::vector::reserve` actual complexity is `O(n log n)`. `log n` comes from fact how vector is resized when it needs to be bigger. Adding proper  `std::vector::reserve` makes it proper `O(n)`.

Comment: @MarekR That's not how it works. It is still constant, even without reserving. This is a standard library guarantee of `std::vector`.

Comment: @MarekR the implicit resize will always be a factor (e.g. 1.5x or 2x or similar) and not a constant which will make this O(n). You shoud hardly ever need to reserve (and getting the reserve wrong can easily make this be quadratic).

Comment: @MikeVine yes that is true that is why `log n` shows in complexity. Resize which lead to reallocate (change in capacity) will happen `O(log n)` times, cost of resize is `O(n)` (all data need to be copied), so this gives `O(n log n)` and it wins with `O(n)` responsible for regular copy.

Comment: @paddy I'm probably wrong, but the reason why I thought it was O(n^2) is that the syntax is vector_name.insert(position, iterator1, iterator2). Since we are inserting more than one value at each "position" using "iterator1" and "iterator2", and after its completion, the range-based loop runs again and performs the same action, I believed it was the same behavior as a loop under another loop.

Comment: @paddy bad wording from my side. By resize I meant change in capacity. When you resize is done beyond capacity all data has to be copied to new buffer with bigger capacity.

Comment: @MarekR this is wrong. The only the cost of the final resize (technically capacity change) is O(n). If we assume doubling the cost of the penultimate resize is n/2, the one before n/4 etc. Or think of it the other way. Go from 1->2 = 1 copy, 2->4 = 2 copies, 4->8 = 4 copies, 8->16 = 8 copies. We end up with a final size n, this requires n/2+n/4+n/8+... _total_ copies which is definitely O(n). So the final complexity is O(n).

Comment: And it doesn't need to be a factor of 2 when changing the capacity, any factor > 1 will result in some constant multiple of `n` total copies

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's also O(1) because `std::vector<T>::max_size()` is an upper bound on the iterations

Comment: @Caleth nice :). Btw I was not just trying to split hairs, but imho choosing number of element and choosing number of vectors to be joined are both completely valid choices for `n`, and that can make the difference between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` or `O(n^whatever)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number oh yes I absolutely agree. There isn't one monolithic "the time complexity", it depends on what you are measuring. Perhaps `O(Σni)`, where ni is the size of the ith inner vector?

Answer (score 0):

O(Σ<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup> m<sub>i</sub>),

Where *n* is the size of the outer vector and *m<sub>i</sub>* is the size of the *i*th inner vector.

If the size of the outer vector and the size of the inner vectors are all O(n), that's equivalent to O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: This is an overly complex answer. The size of the flattened vector is the sum of the sizes of the inner vectors. So the complexity in its simplest representation is O(k) where k is the size of the flattened vector. The second part of this answer is very weird. Why add an arbitrary expression where there's any link between the size of the outer vector and the size of the inner vectors?

Comment: @MikeVine "The size of the flattened vector is the sum of the sizes of the inner vectors" That's literally what I say. In the second case, your *k* is bounded by my *n^2*. Traditionally you talk about varying the size of the input, so defining complexity in terms of the size of the output might also confuse.